# Flutter : how to user confimation dialog before call bloc

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-bloc

i tried to call confiramtion dailog before calling blocprovider but i got this error :

```
BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a DatasendBloc.
        No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to BlocProvider.of<DatasendBloc>().

        This can happen if the context you used comes from a widget above the BlocProvider.

        The context used was: Builder
```

and this is my code and i put it in function and called it from listview.bulder :

```
void _showConfirmationDialog(BuildContext context, postmodel model) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext dialogContext) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Confirm Action'),
        content: Text('Do you want to perform this action?'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Cancel'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(dialogContext); // Close the dialog
            },
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () async {
              // Call the bloc here
              try {
                BlocProvider.of<DatasendBloc>(dialogContext).add(SendData(model));
              } catch (e) {
                print(e);
                await NotificationService.showNotification(
                  title: "Fail",
                  body: "Error occurred, please try again",
                );
              }
              Navigator.pop(dialogContext); // Close the dialog
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
```

the error come from BlocProvider.of(dialogContext).add(SendData(model));. how to solve this?

i have tried called different build context. and i call blocprovider before calling this page like this:

```
child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) => BlocProvider<DatasendBloc>.value(
                      value: _PostingBloc,
                      child: const SaveformApp(),
                    ),
                  )
                    );
                      },
                      
                  child: const Text('List of IDs Inspected'),
                )
```

how to overcome this?

Comment: So in the _showConfirmationDialog method call try to pass the context to the bloc and not the dialogs context which is dialogContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurred because you have provided and created the Bloc in another context.

You can see context as different layers each of them need to have the Bloc created and provided in them. But please note each Bloc provided and created in its context will be independent. So you won't be able to use the State of your generalContext Bloc if you provide and create another Bloc in your Dialog

So there is several ways to solve your problem:

- The one I will recommend is to put a second argument to your `Navigator.pop()` function.
  You can do something like

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext dialogContext) {
      return AlertDialog(
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(dialogContext, true);
            },
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              Navigator.pop(dialogContext, false);
            },
          ),
        ],
     ).then((value) {
    //Call your bloc from general context here
    if(value) {
    //Do your thing if user says no
    } else{
    //Do your thing if user says no
    }
  });
```

I think this is a good practice because it detaches your logic layer from your UI layer and your Bloc remain as independent as possible